# How to bind data in dataGridView from sql database using comboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

I am facing unique problem with my code.
This is the code for showing tables in `comboBox1` its working fine.

ComboBox is filled with school names and when a user select a school in that ComboBox, The students in that school will be shown in DataGridView
Please help.

> Functionality of this application:
>
> 1. Creating a table in sql database(schoolName).
> 2. Selecting table(select School).
> 3. Adding values in the school(student information).
>
> error:
>
> 1. the datagrid in the bottom is not retrieving properly, its showing something else.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
            
SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataTable dtRecords = new DataTable();
dbAdapter.Fill(dtRecords);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecords; //dataGrid
comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecords;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";

con.Close();
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Can u explain the functionality of your application?

Comment: In dataGrid the values are not binding, its showing different things..!
how to get values in datagrid when i select any school from comboBox?

Comment: Functionality of this application:

1. Creating a table in sql database(schoolName).

2. Selecting table(select School).

3. Adding values in the school(student information).

error:

1. the datagrid in the bottom is not retrieving properly, its showing something else.

Comment: ComboBox is filled with school names and when a user select a school in that ComboBox, The students in that school will be shown in DataGridView, is it what you want?

Comment: yes! thats exactly what i want.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx

The SQL query `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` returns information about the tables that exist in database **not the rows of a specefic table**

If you want to the information of that table you can rich that by writing a new query in `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your ComboBox, something like that:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + comboBox1.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dtRecords = new DataTable();
        dbAdapter.Fill(dtRecords);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecords; //dataGrid

        con.Close();
    }
```

This code can fix this problem, but actually there is a bigger problem and It's about your data structure.

This kind of code tells me there is a table for every school and that's not a normalized database.
Lets clear it by an example: Imagine that your manager want to move some students from their school to another school, in this data structure you have to move a record from a table to another table, first you have to find that record that point to our student and then save it in memory and then create a new record in destination table.
In this example:

- There is a lot of works to do (There is a a lot of code to write)
- There is a risk that your data will be crupted.
- What happen if this have to be done in 1000 students??!!

In other hand you can simply create table and named it `schools` that have two main columns: `ID` , `Name`
and then create a table and named it `students` that have three main columns: `ID`, `SchoolID`, `Name`
every school have a unique id and every student have its own id related to its own school by `SchoolID` column.

Comment: yeah. you are correct, first i'll complete this project first.
I am now trying to add values in the selected tables.
how can i use sqlCommand to add values to selected comboboxValueS?

Comment: Are you want to add school names to combo box or insert a new student to specified school in combo box?